# How to clear the session between two consecutive intents?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

We are using bot trees master which uses bot graph dialog for loading graph based dialogs dynamically. We have created a scenario to load multiple intents(whose intents scores are nearly matching). Now the problem I am facing is when I request for single intent , I am getting the bot response and able to enter into next intent but when I request for multiple intents bot is giving the response and when I request for another intent , bot is giving the same response of multiple intents. When bot is entering into multiple intent handler it is not clearing the session and not coming out of that  handler. I have tried using session.endConversation().

To understand about bot graph dialog:
https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2016/11/11/extending-microsofts-bot-framework-with-graph-baseddialogs-/

Can somebody help on this. Thank you

Comment: Why should you clear the session here?

Comment: Can you please add more information about your scenario and a code example

Comment: Hi, i have explained the scenario. Please look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the builder.IntentDialog() used in this project is no longer considered a best practice. Additionally, further support is not expected. Instead, you will want to use bot.Dialog() to create your dialog flows with a .triggerAction(). The trigger matches on phrases which you can set a score to. Unfortunately, it means you will need to recreate the bot-trees project to fit this new model.

You can find information on managing conversations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0), including creating triggers.
If you need a more robust system, you can integrate [LUIS](https://www.luis.ai/home) into your project. Information regarding recognizing intents with LUIS can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-luis?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).